# Why does the W3C validator show error messages for these IMG attributes?

Tags: html, image

I have an IMG tag in my HTML5 document that reads:

```
<img src="elements/background.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" />
```

When I run the document through the W3C validator (doctype is HTML5, encoding is UTF-8), it comes up with two error messages, one for the width attribute and one for the height attribute.  Both say something to the effect of, "Expected a digit but saw % instead."

I checked on the W3C website, and the width and height attributes for the IMG tag both still support percentages in HTML5. What's going on?

Comment: try using style attribute (CSS) instead of the attributes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to W3C:

[...] The attributes, if specified, must have values that are valid non-negative integers.

*[4.8.16 Dimension attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20100624/the-map-element.html#attr-dim-width)*

Change the values to integers or use CSS.

Comment: This was the page I found the info on: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_img.asp).  Nevertheless, you're right, and I successfully implemented my percentages in my CSS stylesheet, and everything checks out.  Thanks!

Comment: FYI, that's not the W3C web site. It's a bogus ad-revenue-generating site that has misled many people in much the same way.

Comment: Wow ... how very disturbing ... I'm glad you told me, it's good to know the site obviously isn't reliable, as I've ended up there a lot.

Comment: @Jonathan Feinberg. W3Schools are a little unlucky on this occasion. HTML4 *did* allow percentages ( http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-length ), and the HTML5 differences from HTML4 document ( http://dev.w3.org/html5/html4-differences/ ) doesn't mention any change in this area.

Comment: It is interesting that HTML5 puts percentages int the back seat.  It seems that they would be more important than ever, given the proliferation of mobile devices and unpredictable screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Using percentages do work, but I guess it has been discontinued in later versions of HTML... I have used it before, like 7 to 8 years ago...

Here is the link which provides the information for the percentages:

*[HTML - Images & Pictures](http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/images.php)*

> Height and width values can also be a percentage. Percentage values
> are relative to the parent HTML element (usually the body), which
> means if you have a parent element like a  element that is the
> whole screen (1024x768), then an image with a height and width of 100%
> will take up that entire body element (1024x768). In our example
> below, we have placed the image in a table element that is about 400
> pixels wide by 200 pixels tall.

Comment: Please provide a description on what that link says about percentages, sometimes the site may no longer become available in which case your answer may no longer be useful

Comment: That www.tizag.com site is very, very fast (at least with JavaScript allow listing)

Comment: But they lowercase the titles using CSS. Very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're misreading the specification, which says "in pixels".

Ref. *[img – image](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/img.html)*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, width and height have been supported as a percentage — very useful for mobile devices and resizing based upon the device resolution.  HTML5 however, does not (sigh).

Just try this dummy with and without the doctype

```
<!-- !doctype html -->
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
  .pics { background-color:black !important;
  border:dashed red 2px;
             color:white;
margin:1px; padding:1px; height:65% !important;
   }
</style>
<div>
<span>just junk<br></span>
<span>
<img class="pics" src="any_image_you_like.jpg" >
</span>
<div>
</body</html>
```

Save and open the file — now resize the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

I inserted this in the header of my page

```
<style>
img
{   
    width: 30%;
    height: auto;
    border: solid 1px black;
}
</style>
```

It does make all of the images on the page have the same width, but this is a page needing just
one image.  It stopped the nasty ululations from the HTML5 validator.

Comment: *[ululation](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ululation#Noun)* - *"The act of ululating; a long, loud, wavering cry or howl."*